# Serilog writes duplicate entries in it's output

Tags: c#, windows-services, serilog

I have written a `Windows Service` which logs its operations using `Serilog`

The application also uses `Autofac` for dependency Injection support and [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) for structured logging.

```
 using Autofac;
 public class ContainerInitiator
 {
       public static IContainer BuildContainer()
       {
          var _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
          var logger = LoggerUtility.CreateLogger();
          _builder.RegisterInstance(logger).As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
          var container = _builder.Build();
          ContainerFactory.SetContainer(container);
          return container;
        }
  }
```

Here is Log utility class

```
public class LoggerUtility
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationName"];
    public static ILogger CreateLogger()
    {
        return GetLoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();
    }
    private static LoggerConfiguration GetLoggerConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings();
        config = config.
           Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", connectionString).
           Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().
           Enrich.WithMachineName().
           Enrich.WithProcessId().
           Enrich.WithThreadId().
           ReadFrom.AppSettings();
        return config;
    }
}
```

Here is my service class, which is logging the activities

```
public class Engine : IEngine
{
      private readonly ILogger _logger;

      public RedistributeEngine(IContainerFactory containerFactory)
      {
           _logger = containerFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
      }

       public void Start()
       {
             _logger.Information("Engine started!");
       }
}
```

As you see below `Seq` logs, it has two entries on the same time!

[image]

Comment: You read the config from the AppSettings twice, this probably adds the same appender twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reading the configuration from App.Settings ***twice***:

```
private static LoggerConfiguration GetLoggerConfiguration()
{
    var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.AppSettings(); // <<<<<<<<<<<< *#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#
    config = config.
       Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", connectionString).
       Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().
       Enrich.WithMachineName().
       Enrich.WithProcessId().
       Enrich.WithThreadId().
       ReadFrom.AppSettings(); // <<<<<<<<<<<< *#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#
    return config;
}
```

Comment: In my case I had a `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(_configuration).CreateLogger();` and a `loggerFactory.AddSerilog();`.

Comment: @MFedatto but that is what the documentation directly says to do? https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/samples/EarlyInitializationSample/Program.cs

Comment: I'm scratching my head as well since I followed the docs as well and get this duplicate behavior. @MFedatto did you ever sort this out?

Comment: @chris I removed the ```loggerFactory.AddSerilog();``` instance.

Comment: @chris If you have configured Serilog in appsettings.json, does Serilog.WriteTo contain both Console and Debug targets? If so, Visual Studio writes both targets to Application Output, therefore you'll see duplicate logs there.

Comment: @wilee What do you mean?
I'm facing a similar issue (duplicate logs in Azure App Insights). 
I have all 3 Serilog Writers (Console, File, AppInsights). 
From local environment it sends to Azure App Insights only one log; after deployed to Azure App Service, it created duplicate logs in Azure App Insights.